# How can I run sites as different users and directory with apache2 and nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: server, apache2

My current setup is /var/www/domain/* with apache2 and nginx as reverse proxy.
I want to move site directory under /home/user/html/* so each website can have user with permission to that folder.

Can you point me somewhere? I've tried to find a lot of guides without any luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the default `000-default.conf` file as a template.  Copy it to a name for your virtual host and make modifications to your custom file.

You can rename the files using these steps:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
$ sudo mv 000-default.conf mysite.conf
$ cd /etc/apache2
$ sudo mv apache2.conf apache2.conf.test
```

Now create your virtual host, "mysite.com".

You can replace the `/home/web/mysite` to any directory.  In your case you can use `/home/{user}/projects/web`.

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
$ sudo cp 000-default.conf mysite.conf
$ sudo mkdir -p /home/web/mysite/www
$ sudo mkdir -p /home/web/mysite/log
```

If the `mysite.com` host doesn't exist, create it locally with:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add it to the `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1  mysite.com
```

Now edit your `mysite.conf` file to point to your `Document Root` choice.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf
```

Make the following changes to this file.  This is the difference between the `000-default.conf` file and your newly created `mysite.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName mysite.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/web/mysite/www


        <Directory />
                Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Includes
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog /home/web/mysite/log/error.log
        CustomLog /home/web/mysite//access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Now enable the new site with:

```
$ sudo a2ensite mysite.conf
```

When making a change to the `Apache` configuration files restart the service with:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Write Permissions to the directory and files of the VirtualHost:

You can use the commands `chown` and `chgrp` to change the owner of the files and folders of `/home/web/mysite/www`.  If they are owned by your userID, you'll have read and write access to the files and folders.

You can also create a specific `group` and add users to the specific group so that user's of that group will have read/write access to the files and folders.